# how to add an openssl created certificate to trusted certificates

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

I used `openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -nodes -out cert.pem -keyout key.pem -days 365` to generate a `cert.pem` and `key.pem` and it has executed correctly. Now what I want is how can I add the openssl generated certificate to trusted certificates so that I don't get greeted with `Your connection isn't private` page before loading my flask https site. Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT:** OS - Windows. I am trying to add the OpenSSL generated certificate to Trusted Root Certification Authorities inside the Microsoft Management console (MMC)

Comment: *Now what I want is how can I add the openssl generated certificate to trusted certificates...*  Trusted certificates for *what*?  What application?  What OS?

Comment: @AndrewHenle I have edited my question with answers to your comment.

Answer (score 0):

depending on the browser you need to run `certutil` with a specific db location:

- chromium-based (most) `-d sql:$HOME/.pki/nssdb`
- firefox `-d %userprofile%\Application Data\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\%randomalphanum%.default\cert8.db`